# Apple Watch Core Motion Data On iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-motion, healthkit, watchconnectivity

So, WatchOS 2 supports the core motion framework and allows an active WatchKit app to access data from the Apple Watch accelerometer. I would like to access that data, but on the iPhone. Is there any other way to do this other than opening an app on the watch that collects that data and transmits it back to the phone via Watch Connectivity.

In Healthkit, all data collected by the watch is synced back to the phone, this means my iPhone app can get straight to the data via a HKSampleQuery. I have wondered if the 'Active Energy' recording in Healthkit are just a collection of the core motion accelerometer data from the watch summated, but Im not sure.

I have thought about using watch connectivity and SendMessage to wake the watch from the iPhone and get the data, but Ive read thats not possible. I can wake the iphone from the watch, but not the other way around.

Ive looked at the WWDC 2015 videos including the 'Whats new in core motion'. it show that you can get core motion data on the watch, but nothing about getting the watch core motion data on the iphone.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: hello, did you find any solution?

Comment: Nope sorry, though I've not looked into this since the post and so things could have changed with WatchOS 3